# After installed Realm in React Native, Can't find module /../../node-pre-gyp

Tags: node.js, react-native, realm, node-modules, realm-mobile-platform

After installed Realm into my React-Native project, while I tried to build my project, I'm getting the following errors:

```
`node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`

> >  Can't find module /../../node-pre-gyp 
> 
> ld: library not found for
> > -lRealmReact clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Even, I tried to remove nodemodules and package-lock.json
and installed npm.

I am doing this in Mac.

But, Same issue happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) **globally**. The command to do so looks like this

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

Comment: Still same issue happening, ld: library not found for -lRealmReact. sorry for the delay in reply.

Comment: did you checked my comment?